# Vertically center text - div dimensions unknown

Tags: css

Here's the example: http://jsfiddle.net/X2sMa/

I need to vertically center the text inside the div, I found [this technique](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/) but whenever I set the div to display: inline-block; the text disappears. Any ideas how to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not looking to support IE7 and under then you can use `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle`, otherwise you are stuck using a table.

Answer (score 0):

You're using absolute positioning in your code for div.mask so you can position the paragraph like:

```
<div class="mask" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;">
    <p style="position: relative; top: 50%;">1500 notes</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Could work but it's not ideal when there are multiple lines of text. Of course one could always add a negative top margin but it's not possible when the lenght of the text varies each time.